# Query tuning help needed (Hash Match and Table Scans)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, performance, query-performance

I need help optimizing the following query (returning ~8k rows):

```
SELECT A.sys_id, 'AppSvrRels' = CAST(SUBSTRING((SELECT (', ' + T.name)
                                FROM (
                                SELECT A.sys_id, AppSvr.name
                                FROM GTS_DataStage.SN.cmdb_ci_appl A
                                LEFT JOIN GTS_DataStage.SN.cmdb_rel_ci X 
                                    ON A.sys_id = X.parent
                                LEFT JOIN GTS_DataStage.SN.cmdb_ci AppSvr 
                                    ON X.child = AppSvr.sys_id 
                                    AND AppSvr.dv_sys_class_name 
                                      IN ('UNIX Server', 'Windows Server', 
                                      'IBM Mainframe', 'Application Server')
                                WHERE A.dv_sys_class_name = 'Application' 
                                 AND A.dv_u_used_for = 'Production' 
                                 AND A.dv_operational_status = 'Deployed') T
                                WHERE A.sys_id = T.sys_id
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 3, 4000) AS NVARCHAR(4000))
FROM GTS_DataStage.SN.cmdb_ci_appl A
WHERE A.dv_sys_class_name = 'Application' AND A.dv_u_used_for = 'Production' 
    AND A.dv_operational_status = 'Deployed'
```

These tables are on the DataStage and I am not allowed to use indexes. Total rowcounts are: 
cmdb_ci_appl: ~20k; cmdb_rel_ci: ~1200k; cmdb_ci: ~800k

The following image shows a section of the execution plan (I can upload the sqlplan file if needed but there's not much else to see):

[image: Execution_Plan_Screenshot]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does "I am not allowed to use indexes" mean? Did you consider adding the index that the plan recommends adding, right there on the third line? You should always be sure to test that this doesn't adversely affect the DML portions of your workload, but that's the optimization step that seems most obvious to try first.

Comment: The next suggestion would be to stop doing this concatenation in SQL Server. Return the data to the presentation tier and let *that* layer concatenate and change the format of the output.

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't be able to use indexes. It seems to me if the recommended index promises a 90% increase you should probably add it. Also if you are not allowed to use proper indexing you're probably not going to be able to get much performance out of your queries.

Comment: @Zane just for clarity, that impact number is not in %. Not trying to take away from your point, of course.

Comment: @AaronBertrand you are absolutely correct sir. I find I type it that way often a habit I am trying to break.

Comment: What's the baseline - how long is this query currently taking to execute?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I can't add indexes because the DBA isn't allowing me to. The baseline runtime is 90-odd minutes to return ~8k rows. FMI: Can someone tell me whether the 'Impact' value in the Index suggestion text should be higher or lower?

Comment: The only way to eliminate table scans is via proper indexing.  Why is your DBA not allowing you to add indexes to queries in order to tune them?  Even if it's a packaged solution, there's very little risk in adding some nonclustered indexes.

Comment: The higher the impact the more effective the index should be.

Comment: Thank you all again. Once I create the recommended index, do I have to do anything else (one-time, periodically, etc.)? Does the index get updated automatically when table/s is/are refreshed (everyday)?

Comment: Aaron Bertrand: Regarding your second suggestion, the presentation layer (Cognos) seems to lack the ability.

SQL Kiwi: I will upload the sqlplan in short order.

Answer (score 1):

Show the DBA those Eager Index Spools in the query plan. SQL Server is so desperate for supporting indexes here, it is creating its own temporary ones on every execution!

There is always more to see in the `sqlplan` file, so please do upload it. A [statistics-only copy of the tables](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914288) in question (or table and index definitions at the very least) would also be useful if you want more than general advice).

This answer was originally a comment on your question. I'll update it if a query plan or DDL is provided.